# Most occured value in database

Tags: sql, oracle

hello by writing like this

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS value_occurrence
FROM table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC;
```

i get this table:

```
name  occurrence
----  ---------
  a        6
  b        5
  c        3
```

But i want the name of most occurred one a.what should i write for this purpose?(i used sql)

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: Just use the first value. Or add `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Comment: using LIMIT 1 gives me an error.SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @ayshee where did you add the `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS value_occurrence
    FROM table
    GROUP BY name
    ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC LIMIT 1;    @Lamak

Comment: I think thuis should be Oracle database, not mysql, judging from OP comment using apex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, this will get you a name occurring as often as or more often than all other names:

```
SELECT name, value_occurrence
FROM (
  SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS value_occurrence
  FROM table
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC )
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

In other words, if there are two names both having the highest number of occurrences, the above query will give you one of them (at random).  If you don't like the random aspect, you could change the `ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC` to `ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC, name` if you like.

If, in the case of a tie, you want to see all the names that are tied for 1st, you can do this:

```
SELECT name, value_occurrence
FROM (
  SELECT name, count(*), dense_rank() over ( partition by null order by COUNT(name) desc) AS value_occurrence_pos
  FROM table
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC )
WHERE value_occurence_pos = 1;
```

Comment: Is the `partition by null` needed?

Comment: No, it's not: the query partition clause is optional.  I include it 90% out of habit and 10% because it make the intention more explicit: it want the `dense_rank()` over all the rows.  It can be omitted though.

Answer (score -3):

Answer 1 is true but 2 error may be occur:

1. **name** is a keyword and is better to change your field name.
2. in SQL Server query editor or query analyzer when a part of query was selected or highlight your query dose not run correct and you will be see an error.sure your a part of your query is not selected.